# How to pass collection to view in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I think I am missing something very simple. But I have no more patience to seek for it, so I need to ask.

I am trying to render view with list of elements of type Event

**In my view I have a foreach loop**:

```
 @foreach ($events as $e)
    ......
    {{ $e->title }}
    ......
 @endforeach
```

**Controller**:

```
    $account = Account::find(\Session::get('account'));
    $events = $account->events()->get();
    return view('events.index')->with('events', $events);
```

In my understanding it should be working this way. But instead I get 
**Invalid argument supplied for foreach()**

**I also tried**:

```
    $account = Account::find(\Session::get('account'));
    $events = $account->events();
    return view('events.index')->with('events', $events);
```

but in this approach my foreach loop will not run even once (no error).

Of course I have everything defined in my models.

**Account:**

```
public function events()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Event');
}
```

One approach which is working is passing data as array like this:

```
    $account = Account::find(\Session::get('account'));
    $events = $account->events()->get()->toArray();
    return view('events.index')->with('events', $events);
```

But then I need to work with array indexes in my view like this:

```
 @foreach ($events as $e)
    ......
    {{ $e['title'] }}
    ......
 @endforeach
```

and I really, really don't want to do it this way.

So please tell my what am I missing.

**Update**:
I can't pass $account to my view and use $account->events in the view because I need to perform some filtering on events before I pass it.

Comment: Try going through output of events ?

Comment: What do you mean nbin? If you mean dumping $events content - well I tried it. But it doesnt help me a lot. This is the result: http://pastebin.com/dvJ3srqv

Comment: The first approach is correct. However since you say you do some additional filtering my question is: is this really your real code?

Comment: Yest, it is my real code. I need to filter my events, but I haven't reached this stage yet. I am struggling with this "no-filter" case first.

Comment: It might seem silly, but try to transform your $events array back into a collection, like this :


`$account = Account::find(\Session::get('account'));
$events = $account->events()->get()->toArray();
return view('events.index')->with('events', collect($events));`


Then dump the $events variable from your view again, and compare it against your first dump to see if there is an obvious difference between the two. (And obviously, check if this new Collection is working as expected, by the way)

Comment: try `$events = $account->events`, without `->get()`. Also I had this issue once too and I fixed it by passing the data to the view like `view()->with(['events' => $events])`.

Answer (score 0):

use like this

```
$account = Account::find(\Session::get('account'));
$events = $account->events;
return view('events.index',['events'=> $events]);
```

Answer (score 0):

use collect:

```
$account = Account::find(\Session::get('account'));
$events = $account->events;
return view('events.index', collect('events'))
```

;